# Как сохранить значение переменной в рекурсии ( значение - это число). Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, функции, рекурсия, переменные

Я решал задачку. В ней нужно найти мультипликативную постоянство, то есть количество раз, которое вы должны умножать цифры,пока не дойдете до единственной цифры.На пример, дано число 39. 3*9 = 27. 2*7 = 14. Затем 1*4 = 4. И останавливаемся. Всего "шагов" 3.Причем, дается только 1 агрумент(number). Вот мой код:

```
from functools import reduce


# amount - total length of blocks
# 67 - number
# ['6','7']
def rec(number, *args):
    summ = args
    amount = 0
    t1 = tuple(map(int, list(str(number))))
    l1 = len(t1)
    amount += l1
    lst = list(summ)
    lst.append(1)
    if amount > 1:
        result1 = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, t1)
        rec(result1, lst)
    else:
        return sum(list(args))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще вариант без строк, с двойной рекурсией. Значение переменной сохраняется через позиционный аргумент (`y` в этом примере):

```
def rec(x, y=0): 
    f = lambda i: i if i<10 else f(i//10) * (i%10)
    return y if x<10 else rec(f(x), y+1)

rec(39)  # 3
```

Comment: Действительно, нужно было просто добавить позиционный аргумент.Странно, как я до этого не додумался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А как вам такое решение в лоб для подсчета кол-ва шагов - грубо конечно (из-за использование строки):

```
def calc(value):
    if value < 10:
        return 0
    res = 1
    for i in str(value):
        res *= int(i)
    return 1 + calc(res)

print(calc(39))
```

Ну или если вам нравятся однострочные варианты:

```
import math

def calc(value):
    return 0 if value < 10 else (1 + calc(math.prod(int(i) for i in str(value))))
```

Без строк можно делать так:

```
def calc(value):
    if value < 10:
        return 0
    res = 1
    while value > 0:
        res *= value % 10
        value //= 10
    return 1 + calc(res)
```